# Exact solutions for lib(ic)

Tags: prolog, floating-accuracy, eclipse-clp, interval-arithmetic, clpr

Using ECLiPSe Prolog's [`lib(ic)`](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic/) I stumbled upon the following problem from [David H. Bailey, "Resolving numerical anomalies in scientific computation."](http://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/) which I was referred to by the [Unum book](https://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781482239867). Actually, it is only part of it. First, let me formulate the equation in terms of `(is)/2`. <s>Also, please note that all these decimal numbers have an exact representation in radix 2 floats (which comprises IEEE)</s>:

```
ECLiPSe Constraint Logic Programming System [kernel]
...
Version 6.2development #21 (x86_64_linux), Wed May 27 20:58 2015
[eclipse 1]: lib(ic).
...
Yes (0.36s cpu)
[eclipse 2]: X= -1, Y = 2, Null is 0.80143857*X+1.65707065*Y-2.51270273.

X = -1
Y = 2
Null = 0.0
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

So this is <s>truly</s> 0.0 (<s>no rounding at all</s>). But now the same with `$=` in place of `is`:

```
[eclipse 3]: X= -1, Y = 2, Null $= 0.80143857*X+1.65707065*Y-2.51270273.

X = -1
Y = 2
Null = 2.2204460492503131e-16__2.2204460492503131e-16
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

This interval does not contain 0.0. I am aware that interval arithmetic often is a bit too approximate as in:

```
[eclipse 4]: 1 $= sqrt(1).

Delayed goals:
    0 $= -1.1102230246251565e-16__2.2204460492503131e-16
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

But at least the equation holds! However, in the first case zero is no longer included. Evidently I have not understood something. I tried also `eval/1` but to no avail.

```
[eclipse 5]: X= -1, Y = 2, Null $= eval(0.80143857*X+1.65707065*Y-2.51270273).

X = -1
Y = 2
Null = 2.2204460492503131e-16__2.2204460492503131e-16
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

What is the reason for `Null` not including `0.0`?

---

(Edit after @jschimpf's surprising answer)

Here is the quotation from the book page 187 that I interpreted as meaning that the numbers are represented exactly (now <s>stroked through</s>).

> Use a {3,5}, environment, the one that can simulate IEEE *single* precision. The input values are exactly representable. ...
> {-1, 2}
> ...
> That did the job, computing the *exact* answer with fewer than *half the bits* used by ...

Otherwise the statement page 184 holds:

> > ...
> >
> > 0.80143857 *x* + 1.65707065 *y* = 2.51270273
>
> The equations certainly look innocent enough. Assuming exact decimal inputs, this
> system is solved exactly by *x* = -1 and *y* = 2.

Here is it rechecked with SICStus' `library(clpq)`:

```
| ?- {X= -1,Y=2,
     A = 80143857/100000000,
     B = 165707065/100000000,
     C = 251270273/100000000,
     Null = A*X+B*Y-C}.
X =  -1,
Y = 2,
A = 80143857/100000000,
B = 33141413/20000000,
C = 251270273/100000000,
Null = 0 ? 
yes
```

So -1, 2 are the exact solutions.

---

#### A precise formulation

Here is a reformulation that does not have rounding problems in the input coefficients, still the solution is just -∞...+∞. Thus trivially correct, but not useable.

```
[eclipse 2]: A = 25510582, B = 52746197, U = 79981812, 
C = 80143857, D = 165707065, V = 251270273,
A*X+B*Y$=U,C*X+D*Y$=V.

A = 25510582
B = 52746197
U = 79981812
C = 80143857
D = 165707065
V = 251270273
X = X{-1.0Inf .. 1.0Inf}
Y = Y{-1.0Inf .. 1.0Inf}


Delayed goals:
    52746197 * Y{-1.0Inf .. 1.0Inf} + 25510582 * X{-1.0Inf .. 1.0Inf} $= 79981812
    80143857 * X{-1.0Inf .. 1.0Inf} + 165707065 * Y{-1.0Inf .. 1.0Inf} $= 251270273
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several issues conspire here to create confusion:

1. other than claimed, the three constants in the example
   do *not* have exact representations as double floats.
2. it is not true that the initial example involves no rounding.
3. the seemingly correct result in the first example is actually due to a
   fortunate rounding error. Other computation orders give different results.
4. the exact result, given the nearest double float representation of
   the constants, is indeed not zero but 2.2204460492503131e-16.
5. interval arithmetic can only give accurate results when the inputs
   are accurate, which isn't the case here.  The constants have to be
   widened into intervals that include the desired decimal fraction.
6. relational arithmetic like the one offered by lib(ic) does by nature
   not guarantee a particular evaluation order. For that reason the rounding
   errors can differ from the ones encountered during functional evaluation.
   The results will however be accurate with respect to the given constants.

The following goes into a bit more detail.  As I will demonstrate some
points using ECLiPSe queries, a quick word beforehand about the syntax:

- two floats separated by a double underscore, such as `0.99__1.01`
  denote an interval constant with lower and upper bound, in this case
  a number in the vicinity of 1.
- two integers separated by a single underscore, such as `3_4`
  denote a rational constant with numerator and denominator, in this
  case *three quarters*.

To demonstrate point (1), convert the float representation of
0.80143857 into a rational.  This gives the precise fraction
3609358445212343/4503599627370496, which is close, but not identical,
to the intended decimal fraction 80143857/100000000.  The floating point
representation is therefore *not* exact:

```
?- F is rational(0.80143857), F =\= 80143857_100000000.
F = 3609358445212343_4503599627370496
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

The following shows how the result depends on the evaluation order
(point 3 above; note that I have simplified the original example by
getting rid of the irrelevant multiplications):

```
?- Null is -0.80143857 + 3.3141413 - 2.51270273.
Null = 0.0
Yes (0.00s cpu)

?- Null is -2.51270273 + 3.3141413 - 0.80143857.
Null = 2.2204460492503131e-16
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

The order dependence proves that rounding errors occur (point 2).  For those familiar with floating point operations, it is in fact easy to see that
when adding `-0.80143857 + 3.3141413`, two bits of precision from `0.80143857`
get lost while adjusting the exponents of the operands.  In fact it is
this lucky rounding error that gives the OP his seemingly correct result!

In reality, the second result is more accurate with respect to the
floating point representations of the constants.  We can prove this
by repeating the computations using precise rational arithmetic:

```
?- Null is rational(-0.80143857) + rational(3.3141413) - rational(2.51270273).
Null = 1_4503599627370496
Yes (0.00s cpu)

?- Null is rational(-2.51270273) + rational(3.3141413) - rational(0.80143857).
Null = 1_4503599627370496
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

As the additions are done with precise rationals, the result is now
order-independent, and because `1_4503599627370496 =:= 2.2204460492503131e-16`,
this confirms the non-zero floating point result obtained above (point 4).

How can interval arithmetic help here?  It works by computing with
intervals that enclose the true value, such that results will always
be accurate with respect to the inputs.  So it is crucial to have
input intervals (*bounded reals* in ECLiPSe terminology) that enclose
the desired true value.  These can be obtained by either writing them
down explicitly, such as `0.80143856__0.80143858`;
by converting from a precise number, for instance a rational using 
`breal(80143857_100000000)`; or by instructing the parser to automatically
widen all floating point numbers into *bounded real* intervals, as follows:

```
?- set_flag(syntax_option, read_floats_as_breals).
Yes (0.00s cpu)

?- Null is -0.80143857 + 3.3141413 - 2.51270273.
Null = -8.8817841970012523e-16__1.3322676295501878e-15
Yes (0.00s cpu)

?- Null is -2.51270273 + 3.3141413 - 0.80143857.
Null = -7.7715611723760958e-16__1.2212453270876722e-15
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

Both results now contains zero, and it becomes apparent how the
precision of the result depends on the evaluation order.

Comment: Consequently, direct float values should not be interpreted as exact values, but as the intervals they might be when coming from a decimal representation.

Comment: Currently, the syntax of intervals is subject to rounding too, so this is an inherent problem: `writeq(1.0000000000000000000000002__1.0000000000000000000000003).
1.0__1.0`. Instead, there should be a `representation_error` or similar.